# how to know the first ready state of DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, document-ready

i am trying to get the first ready state of the DOM. the second, third, etc is not interesting me, but the first one. is there any trick to get the first ready state of DOM?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // is it the first ready state?
});
```

Comment: `$(window).load( function() {                    });`

Comment: Handle the [`readystatechange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/readystatechange) yourself. jQuery's document ready handler tells you when the document is "ready", so your callback function will be called once, not on each ready state change.

Comment: _document.onreadystatechange = function () { 
    alert(document.readyState);
}​_

Comment: How many do you expect? Seems there are only [two `readystate`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.readyState), and [one `readystatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/readystatechange).

Comment: @nnnnnn i think it is same as `document.DOMContentLoaded` or JQUERY `$(document).ready()`

Comment: @Bergi - There are three states (according to the page you linked to).

Comment: so, there are 2 states: ``complete`` and ``interactive`` . what is ``interactive`` again?

Comment: No, there are 3 states, and the page Bergi linked to explains what all three are. jQuery's document ready should fire when the state changes to `"interactive"`, _but_ note jQuery has extra code to simulate this in browsers that don't support it directly.

Comment: i think `interactive` is when document is partially loaded and `complete` is when document is loaded as a whole!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, you're using jQuery. Have a look at [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/): There is only one `ready` event! I will never fire multiple times. [Internally](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L851), this is even handled with a [Promise](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), so it *cannot* fire multiple times.

Comment: great, you quenched my thirst for answer :D

Answer (score 3):

There are 4 readyState possible values:

- uninitialized - Has not started loading yet
- loading - Is loading
- interactive - Has loaded enough and the user can interact with it
- complete - Fully loaded

To see it's value use this code:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState === YourChoice) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I could not catch the `uninitialized` readyState. (but why should I need it?)

If you need a listener for complete load of the DOM, use:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', YourListener);
```

or

```
document.addEventListener('load', YourListener);
```

or even

```
window.onload = YourListener;
```

for jquery:

```
$(document).on("DOMContentLoaded", function() { });
```

or

```
$(document).on("load", function() { });
```

or

```
$(window).on("load", function() { });
```

Comment: so, man moral of the story is that the first readystate will be considered `loading`?

Comment: _"I could not catch the uninitialized readyState."_ - I would expect it starts in that state, so there wouldn't be an associated change event. _"but why should I need it?"_ - Indeed.

Comment: @AspiringAqib usually yes, I guess that for iFrames it is possible to catch the `uninitialized` event