# Window.onload vs script defer

Tags: javascript, html

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13859236) it's said, that there are **4 readyState** possible values for html documents:

> uninitialized - Has not started loading yet
>  loading - Is loading
>   interactive - Has loaded enough and the user can interact with it
>   complete - Fully loaded

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5250888/2022068) it's said that basically, defer tells the browser to wait "until it's ready" before executing the javascript in that script block. Usually this is after the DOM has finished loading and `document.readyState == 4`

So the question what is executed first and why - the `<script defer src="...">` or `window.onload=function(){...} ?`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Read on to http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#attr-script-defer:

> There are three possible modes that can be selected using these
>   attributes. If the `async` attribute is present, then the script will be
>   executed asynchronously, as soon as it is available. **If the `async`
>   attribute is not present but the `defer` attribute is present, then the
>   script is executed when the page has finished parsing.** If neither
>   attribute is present, then the script is fetched and executed
>   immediately, before the user agent continues parsing the page.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-end tells you that deferred scripts run first:

> …
>   Execute the first script in the list of scripts that will execute when the document has finished parsing.
>   …

Then the `DOMContentLoaded` event:

> Queue a task to fire a simple event that bubbles named DOMContentLoaded at the Document.

`load` events fire after both of these, always.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. Could you explain why DOMContentLoaded event is not in my list?

Comment: @PashaTurok: Your list is a list of `readyState`s, not events. `DOMContentLoaded` is fired between `"interactive"` and `"complete"`; see steps 1, 4, and 7 of “The end”.